# Automatically avoid broken internal hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref

I am using pdftex and the hyperref package. I have a number of automatically generated `\hyperlink{<label>}{<text>}`, which point to other automatically generated `\hypertarget{<label>}{<text>}`.

But since the two are generated independently, I don't know a priori whether a given label exists or not. The default behaviour when hyperlinking to an inexistent target is to put a "Go to page 1" link, which is completely useless for the user.

Is it possible to change that default behaviour to either

- put no link when the link would be broken, or
- point the link to itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added code for this to the `ydoc` package (beta version only), which is an alternative to `ltxdoc`/`doc`. There the macro descriptions are hyperlinked to the place where the macros are defined and vice versa.

To avoid dead links for internal macros which aren't described in the user manual part I remember each one by defining a macro like `\defined@<name>` when I set the `\hypertarget{}`. This definitions are also written to the `.aux` file so that they are available at the beginning of the document. The `\hyperlink` is then only set if `\defined@<name>` exist.

Comment: My goal was in fact to propose something to Joseph Wright for possible inclusion in `l3doc`, so `ydoc` is very relevant. I remember issues with the catcode of `@` being other when reading the `.aux` file. How do you make sure that `\def\defined@...` actually defines `\defined@...` and not `\defined` delimited by `@...`? Are you using a `\csname` construction?

Comment: @Bruno: Sorry, I can't follow you right now. Yes, the `@` is *other* while reading the `.aux` file , which is what you want in this situation. I'm using `\global\@namedef{href@desc@<macro>}{}` and `\global\@namedef{href@impl@<macro>}{}` for the description and implementation.

Comment: @Martin: but then `\@namedef` should be tokenized as `\@`, followed by `n`, `a`, etc.?

Comment: @Bruno: dammit, sorry, I had a long day :-) I meant the catcode of the `@` in the `.aux` file is *letter*, not *other*. LaTeX itself uses macro with `@` there, like `\@writefile`. See lines 1366-68 and 3900 of `latex.ltx`, there the `.aux` file is read and both times `\makeatletter` is used.

Comment: @Martin: I should have run some tests myself. So in the end, you do use a csname construction, but not because of the `@`, rather for the macro name. Thanks for the pointer to `latex.ltx`.

Comment: @Bruno: yes, it's because of the macro name. I can't recall the exact reason right now -- I think to support also weird macro names, or because it is simpler at this position to work with the name instead of the macro itself.