# Calculate the hash (MD5 or otherwise) of a string

Tags: macros, programming

I'm trying to cache the results of a macro, similar to [that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16016/how-to-cache-the-results-of-a-macro), but the argument of the macro can contain arbitrary characters and it's not suitable to be inside `\csname ... \endcsname`.

So, I'm wondering: surely some of the TeX core or packages contain functionality to calculate a hash, MD5 or otherwise (I don't really care which). But… I can't find it. The only result I've got from `grep`'ing my TeXlive tree is `pdfmdfivesum`, but it only works on files, not strings.

So: are there ready-made hash calculation macros/packages available somewhere?

Comment: Your mention of `\pdfmdfivesum` suggests you've looked at using the pdfTeX primitive. It doesn't need a file, it needs `<general text>`, so seems suitable. However, it's tied to pdfTeX. Is that OK, or do we need a solution for other engines too? (LuaTeX can break out to Lua, XeTeX can't, classical TeX also more tricky.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\pdfmdfivesum` also works on arbitrary strings:

```
\pdfmdfivesum{Hello World}
```

Result:

```
B10A8DB164E0754105B7A99BE72E3FE5
```

The hex string can be decoded to save space:

```
\pdfunescapehex{\pdfmdfivesum{Hello World}}
```

`\pdfmdfivesum` is expandable and can be used inside `\edef`.

`\pdfmdfivesum` works on file only, when the keyword `file` is given:

```
\pdfmdfivesum file {<filename>}
```

### Package `pdftexcmds`

`\pdfmdfivesum` is available in pdfTeX in both modes DVI and PDF.
Package `pdftexcmds` defines missing pdfTeX primitives in LuaTeX.
The package also works in plain TeX (`\input pdftexcmds.sty`).
The command names are using the prefix `\pdf@` instead of `\pdf`:

```
\pdf@mdfivesum{Hello World}
```

### XeTeX

- Older versions, e.g., XeTeX (3.14159265-2.6-0.99992), do not support MD5 sums.
- `\pdffivesumm` was added around version 0.99993 from pdfTeX and later renamed to `\mdfivesum`. Thus, the current version (3.14159265-2.6-0.99996)
  calculates MD5 sums via `\mdfivesum`. Also keyword `file` is supported as in pdfTeX.

Comment: Can anyone give me a hint, how to get only the first three signs of the hash?