# How to include a hash of a source file in the final PDF file?

Tags: pdftex, revision-control

Suppose I've got a poem.tex source file.

Is there a way to include a hash of the source file as text in the final PDF? I usually use `pdflatex` to generate PDF files.

I am looking for something like the result of `shasum poem.tex`, looking like this:

> c0c0fa9a776ea1891264c884e0e69dbde6142c4a,

being added somewhere to the body of the output file of the `pdflatex poem.tex` command.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Related thread with a lot of useful methods: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252566/calculate-the-hash-md5-or-otherwise-of-a-string

Comment: For what purpose? A hash of a source file _might_ have no relationship to the hash of text in a .PDF after the source is included in the .PDF and later extracted. It could depend on exactly how you expect the hash to be used, possibly even on the platform used to view the .PDF.

Comment: @user2338816, The file is a set of mathematical equations and theorems. It will be forked, modified and used by a lot of people. The changes might be hard to spot at first glance, so I wanted to have an indicator of what version of the file when it gets printed. I do not use any VCS yet, so Git or SVN is not an option.

Comment: That sounds more like a simple version control number rather than a hash. You might consider using one that way. By using a hash, it implies that users can obtain the same value by running the same hash function, and that might not work often.

Comment: @user2338816 The point is that I don't want to bother with changing the version number every time I modify the file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

pdfTeX contains the primitive `\pdfmdfivesum` for this purpose, available in recent XeTeX as `\mdfivesum` and implemented in Lua for LuaTeX in the `pdftexcmds` package. Using the latter as a wrapper we might have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\ifx\pdf@filemdfivesum\undefined\def\pdf@filemdfivesum#{\mdfivesum file}\fi
\let\filesum\pdf@filemdfivesum
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\cfoot{\filesum{\jobname}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

The primitive syntax (if we assume pdfTeX/XeTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\ifx\pdfmdfivesum\undefined
  \let\pdfmdfivesum\mdfivesum
\fi
\edef\filesum{\pdfmdfivesum file {\jobname}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\cfoot{\filesum}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not work with `\include` or `\input`'ed files, though. :(

Comment: @lindhe Hashing all of the files is of course more tricky, but the underlying idea is the same. You just have to arrange to _e.g._ modifying `\input` to has the file as it opens it.

Comment: @lindhe: You can use the `filehook` package to hook into `\input` etc. to calculate a hash of the subfile. I would suggest accumulating all hashes and then calculate a final hash over them.

Answer (score 8):

This stores the checksum in variable `\shasum`. All the `\string\\\string\\` is needed to get `\\\\` into the shell stream. Option `--shell-escape` is needed of course. The advantage of this solution is that the result is stored in a macro, which is more natural IMHO.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`\%=11
\immediate\write18{printf "\string\\\string\\edef\string\\\string\\shasum{%s}" `shasum \jobname.tex | awk '{print $1}'` > \jobname.sha}
\endgroup
\input{\jobname.sha}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The checksum is \shasum.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is only needed with Knuth's TeX; see the answer by Joseph.

Comment: @MartinSchröder And that's a reason for a downvote? `:-O`

Comment: @yo' See the same comment on my post ;-) Ridiculous!

Comment: @yo': The answer is of course o.k. but completely ignores the command built into pdfTeX and LuaTeX since ca. 10 years (and XeTeX). As such I deem it not useful.

Comment: @MartinSchröder well, unlike the other answer, this one allows for arbitrary has functions as long as they're available as linux shell tools, not only MD5. So while the other answer is better, this one has its value as well.

Comment: If I can add a consideration, consider that MD5 is deprecated on many levels nowadays. If the checksum is included in the output for security reasons, an MD5 hash is completely useless. Using a SHA checksum can be recommended, even if pdfTeX implements MD5 internally.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative Linux/Unix - shell-escape based approach (although there is `\pdfmdfivesum file {yourfilename}`)

It writes the hash to a file and reads it back to the original file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \immediate\write18{shasum \jobname.tex | awk '{print $1}'>  \jobname.hash}
}

\cfoot{\input{\jobname.hash}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A variation with reading to a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newread\hashfile

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \immediate\write18{shasum \jobname.tex | awk '{print $1}'>  \jobname.hash}
  \openin\hashfile=\jobname.hash
  \read\hashfile to \filehash
  \closein\hashfile
}

\cfoot{\filehash}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is only needed with Knuth's TeX; see the answer by Joseph.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: And that's why it deserves a downvote? That's rather harsh. It is an alternative, not more and not less. If I would downvote any 'unnecessary' alternative by users I would have a long list to pursue! The time of the downvote and the comment is very clear ...

Comment: I think you could avoid the temporary `.hash` file by using the “piped input” feature.